# I want to grep a pattern inside a file n list that file based on current date

Tags: shell

```
ls -l | grep "Feb 22" | grep -l "good" *
```

This is the command i am using . i have 4 files among which one file contains the world good . I want to list that file . And that file creation is the current date . based on both the criteria i want to list that file

Comment: Hi, Please try with my solution, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
find . -type f -newermt 2018-02-21 ! -newermt 2018-02-22 -exec grep -l good {} \;
```

or

```
find . -type f -newermt 2018-02-21 ! -newermt 2018-02-22 | xargs grep -l good
```

And please, [*don't parse ls output*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: find: missing argument to `-exec'
 I am getting this error

Answer (score 1):

Hi Try with below command. How it works? Here `find` command with parameter `-mtime -1` will search for files with current date in current directory as well as its sub directories. Each file found will be pass to `grep` command one at a time. `grep` command will check for the string in that file (means each file passes to it)

```
find . -mtime -1 -type f | xargs grep -i "good"
```

In the above command it will list all the file with current date. To list a files of specific kind you below command. Here I am listing only txt files.

```
find . -name "*.txt" -mtime -1 -type f | xargs grep -i "good"
```

`find .` is for running it from current directory (dot means current directory). To run it from a specific directory path modify like below:-

```
find /yourpath/ -name "*.txt" -mtime -1 -type f | xargs grep -i "good"
```

Also `grep -i` means "ignore case". For a specific case just use `grep "good"`

Comment: The pattern of date is "Feb 22" . where shud i include this

Comment: can you provide me the name of the file? I will do it for you. Only one name is fine. like FileFeb22.txt. Also just try with my suggestion, it will find out all files which are created today.

Comment: File1.txt File2.txt File3.txt , Here file 2 contains "Good" in it whose creation date is the current . I want to list File2 based on the conditions :                         current date and The word Good in it

Comment: @Aakashk.u., I modified my answer. Look at the second option. If it fixes your requirement please accept my answer. Thanks